# How can I add :hover without an animation with jquery stop working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

This code is working:

https://jsfiddle.net/9du21gtn/

But if I had this:

```
.linguait:hover{
    border: 3px solid #888888;;
    -webkit-transition: border 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: border 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: border 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: border 500ms linear;
    transition: border 500ms linear;    
}
.linguait:hover > .it{
    color: #888888;
    -webkit-transition: color 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: color 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: color 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: color 500ms linear;
    transition: color 500ms linear;
}
```

It isn't working anymore:

https://jsfiddle.net/9du21gtn/1/

How can I do?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Please [edit] your question to include the code in the second fiddle (can be runnable or just formatted code) as well as a specific description of what isn't working.

Comment: Hi, try to be more specific so we or anyone else can help you

Comment: *"It isn't working anymore"*  isn't a proper problem description. Explain what you expect it to do and what it isn't doing as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are overriding the transition attributes in the hover class. This is the working code:

```js
.linguait{
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 3px solid #c8c8c8;
    top:50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    right: 5%;
    margin-right: -2px;
    -webkit-transition: border 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: border 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: border 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: border 500ms linear;
    transition: border 500ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: border 500ms, right 2s, margin-right 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
    transition: border 500ms, right 2s, margin-right 2s, transform 2s; 
}

.linguait.active{
    right:25%;
    margin-right: -10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: right 2s, margin-right 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
    transition: right 2s, margin-right 2s, transform 2s; 
}

.it{
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    top: 7.5px;
    -webkit-transition: color 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: color 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: color 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: color 500ms linear;
    transition: color 500ms linear;
}

.linguait:hover{
    border: 3px solid #888888;;
}
.linguait:hover > .it{
    color: #888888;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!